# navigation li items not correct css ... Have a look

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, navigation

I have a website build on the Wordpress Platform whith an horizontal menu.

When viewed in ie 9+ and firefox it seems okay, but on ie8- the menu css classes seems not right.

I am struggling to find the problem in the css using firebug.

Could someone please give me a hand and help me with this problem...

my website is: [www.markett.nl](http://www.markett.nl)

asfasf

Comment: You should post your code and maybe an image showing what it looks like and another one showing how it should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using HTML5 tags like `header, nav, footer`, which are not supported in IE8 and below. If you want this to work in IE8 and below, just add this script in your `head` :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

if you look at your IE8 interpreted source - you'll see - IE8 doesnt render nav-Tag proberly. This is because nav-Tag is HTML5 standard - and <IE9 is not able to deal with that. That's why you need to implement html5.js - to solve that issue. You did - but [the file](http://www.markett-traprenovatie.nl/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/html5.js) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you have used css3 properties in your code.  Ie8 dosent support css3.
A work around for this is u can add PIE.htc in your project, here is a link check it out

[PIE.HTC](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Well the main problem that arises is that IE8 and older dont implement the  tag correctly. I would make another wrapper or change it  to a div. Also you should left your elements float some more for IE. Hope it helps u one step further.